# validation rule to stop delete

Tags: visualforce, soql, custom-object, validation, delete

I know this sounds a bit strange but I want to stop a deletion call so that I can test an error handler on my visualforce page. How can I go about setting up a validation rule that will stop a delete for a custom object Relationship_Detail__c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can only do this with a validation rule if the object in question is the child in a master-detail relationship. If so:

1. Set up a rollup summary field on the parent object which counts the number of child records.
2. Set up a validation rule on the parent object which prevents the rollup field value from decreasing:

   If( 
       PriorValue(MyRollupField__c) > MyRollupField__c,
       true,
       false
   )

Messy and I can't guarantee if would work, but I seem to remember doing something similar a while back.

If that doesn't work, a simple trigger will:

```
trigger DeletePrevention on MyObject__c (before delete) {

    for (MyObject__c mo : Trigger.old) {

        mo.addError('Unable to delete record!');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose for the "mo.('Unable to delete record!');"? I tried doing that but it gives me an error message saying  "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SOBJECT:Relationship_Detail__c].(String)"

Comment: made small correction to the code (.addError)